# Does Apache save sessions

Tags: php, apache, session

I am developing a PHP MySQL based web application. Now what I want is to monitor the web logging based on sessions.

Is there any way to customize the Apache log file so that it would capture PHP sessions?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to be able to filter an apache log file based on PHP session data ?

Answer (score 1):

The default `session.save_path` is set to `""`. You can find out the current path with

[session_save_path() — Get and/or set the current session save path](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your own session handler: http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-set-save-handler.php